# React Native - Picker not showing up even after writing the correct code

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and learning from a course. Unfortunately, I'm stuck in a problem where my picker doesn't show up. Even after styling my CardSection, it is not working. Here is a the code. Please help

I've tried styling the CardSection but it doesn't seem to be working

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Picker, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { employeeUpdate } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';

class EmployeeCreate extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        label='Name'
                        placeholder='Jane'
                        value={this.props.name}
                        onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'name', value })}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        label='Phone'
                        placeholder='555-555-5555'
                        value={this.props.phone}
                        onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'phone', value })}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Shift</Text>
                    <Picker
                        style={{ flex: 1 }}
                        selectedValue={this.props.shift}
                        onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'shift', value })}
                    >
                        <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="Sunday" />
                    </Picker>
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Button>Create</Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    pickerTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 20
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { name, phone, shift } = state.employeeForm;

    return { name, phone, shift };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeeUpdate })(EmployeeCreate);
```

Here is the CardSection

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.constainerStyle, props.style]}>
            {props.children}
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    constainerStyle: {
        bottomBorderWidth: 1,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderColor: '#DDD',
        position: 'relative'
    }
};

export { CardSection };
```

I expect the CardSection to show up like a Picker

Comment: Maybe add `flex: 1` to CardSection? Because if CardSection is a parent it needs to have some width and height, so Picker can take full space with `flex: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Adding the following styling to the picker resolves it

```
style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
```